# Align appearance of listings and algorithm packages

Tags: listings, algorithms

I want the output generated by the listings and the algorithm package to be the same.

Consider the following minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,final,parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Numbers}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{Frame}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\lstset{  
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=fixed,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,       % keyword style
numbers=left,
frame=single,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
language={SPARQL},
numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{Numbers},
rulecolor=\color{Frame},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false
}

\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{First}\mbox{}

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT *
WHERE {?s ?p ?o.}
\end{lstlisting}

\paragraph{Second}\mbox{}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{doSomething}{params}
    \If{params == correct}
        \State   doIt
    \EndIf
\EndFunction            
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

and its output

[image]

Both listings should be displayed exactly the same. The main requirement are the line numbers outside the box. Specifying colors for line numbers and boxes would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility (the code conatains explanatory comments; see also below):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper,final,parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{bera}% nice monospaced font with possibility for boldfaced characters

\definecolor{Numbers}{RGB}{200,34,34}
\definecolor{Frame}{RGB}{55,155,198}

% set distance between numbers and contents for both
% environments
\newlength\algnumbsep
\setlength\algnumbsep{5pt}
% set font properties for numbers in both environments
\newcommand\numberfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\color{Numbers}}
% set font properties for text in algorithmic and basic style for listings
\newcommand\basicfont{\small\ttfamily}

\lstset{  
basicstyle=\basicfont,
columns=fixed,
keywordstyle=\bfseries,       % keyword style
numbers=left,
numbersep=\algnumbsep,
frame=single,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
language={SPARQL},
numberstyle=\numberfont,
rulecolor=\color{Frame},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false
}


% add color to numbers in algpseudocode
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\numberfont#1}%

\makeatletter
% add color to frame in algorithm "boxed" style
\renewcommand\fs@boxed{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\setbox\@currbox\vbox{\hbadness10000
    \moveleft3.4pt\vbox{\advance\hsize by6.8pt
      \color{Frame}\hrule \hbox to\hsize{\vrule\kern3pt
        \vbox{\kern3pt\box\@currbox\kern3pt}\kern3pt\vrule}\hrule}}}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
% add monospaced font, change \leftmargin and add control for number separation
% in the algorithmic environment
\renewenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]%
   {\basicfont%
   \edef\ALG@numberfreq{#1}%
   \def\@currentlabel{\theALG@line}%
   %
   \setcounter{ALG@line}{0}%
   \setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}%
   %
   \let\\\algbreak%
   %
   \expandafter\edef\csname ALG@currentblock@\theALG@nested\endcsname{0}%
   \expandafter\let\csname ALG@currentlifetime@\theALG@nested\endcsname\relax%
   %
   \begin{list}%
      {\ALG@step}%
      {%
      \rightmargin\z@%
      \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent2em%
      \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
      \labelsep\algnumbsep \topsep 0.2em%\skip 1.2em 
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}%
         {\labelwidth 0.5em}%
         {\labelwidth 1.2em}%
      \leftmargin0pt%\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}% Ok. the perfect leftmargin :-))
      \ALG@tlm\z@%
      }%
   \setcounter{ALG@nested}{0}%
   \ALG@beginalgorithmic%
   }%
   {% end{algorithmic}
   % check if all blocks are closed
   \ALG@closeloops%
   \expandafter\ifnum\csname ALG@currentblock@\theALG@nested\endcsname=0\relax%
   \else%
      \PackageError{algorithmicx}{Some blocks are not closed!!!}{}%
   \fi%
   \ALG@endalgorithmic%
   \end{list}%
   }%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\paragraph{First}\mbox{}

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT *
WHERE {?s ?p ?o.}
\end{lstlisting}

\paragraph{Second}\mbox{}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{doSomething}{params}
    \If{params == correct}
        \State   doIt
    \EndIf
\EndFunction            
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Simply changing `\numberfont` you change the font attributes for numbers in both environments, changing `\algnumbsep` you control the separation between numbers and contents for both algorithms. Changing the definitions for the colors "Numbers" and "Frame", you can select the desired color for the numbers, and frame, respectively, in both environments. Changong \basicfont you simultaneously set the font for the text in `algorithmic` and for the `basicstyle` key in `listings`.

Comment: Very nice! Thank your very much. :)
Two minor issues though: The line numbers are not exactly in the same style. For the second (algorithmic) listing, the line numbers are \ttfamily, if I am not mistaken. And looking at the second listing itself, the font does not seem to be monospaced; at least the characters are not aligned in fixed columns as in the first listing (same as in my min. working example).

Comment: @Thomas you were right about the numbers; now it's fixed. Regarding the `columns=fixed` option for listings, I am afraid that implementing it in `algorithmicx` will require a lot more work, and I'm sorry, but I don't feel like doing it.

Comment: Thank you, Gonzalo! :) I really appreciate your work. And it is just that I don't understand why the second listing doesn't look like monospaced, fixed-column font. Didn't mean to ask you to implement it.
Edit: With `lmodern` instead of `bera` the second listing actually looks "monospaced, fixed-column".